# Find critical points of an ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Find the critical points and the solution of the ODE system. Parameters $k_t, \space k_i $ are both positive constants.

$$\frac{d \vec u}{dt} = k_t \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}u+k_i\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec u(0) = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I have tried but can't find the critical points. Setting the RHS to $0$ doesn't seem to help much since both ODE's are not satisfied for the same $\vec u$.

Any ideas?

Comment: $k_t$ and $k_i$ are both positive constants. Correct?

Comment: @Variable correct!

Comment: What methods have you learned? Undetermined coefficients, variation of parameters, Laplace transforms?

Comment: @Variable not Laplace transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $A$ is singular (as is the case here), there may be no critical points and that is the case here.

We can quickly draw a phase portrait to see this (I randomly chose constants and all phase portraits will look like this, with the exception of the direction arrows changing direction).

[image]

If $A$ were nonsingular, we may have been able to transform it to a homogeneous system using a change of variables to make life easier.

Even though $A$ is singular, we may still be able to solve the system using many methods that can include Undetermined Coefficients, Variation of Parameters (VoP), Laplace Transforms, etc. Lets use VoP with the [*Matrix Exponential*](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/NonhomoSys.pdf). We are going to mimic Solution 3.

We have the system  (I changed the constants to something easier)

$$\frac{d \vec u}{dt} = a \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}u+ b\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \end{bmatrix} \\ \vec u(0) = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

See linked notes for details and please rework details.

$$A = a \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, f(t) = b\begin{bmatrix}1  \\0 \end{bmatrix}, \vec u(0) = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues / eigenvectors are $\lambda_1 = 0, \vec v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1  \\1 \end{bmatrix}, \lambda_2 = -2a, \vec v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$.

$e^{t A} = P e^{t D} P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & e^{-2 a t} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/2 \\-1/2 & 1/2\end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1 + e^{-2 a t} & 1-e^{-2 a t} \\1-e^{-2 a t} & 1+e^{-2 a t} \end{bmatrix}$

The solution to the initial value problem is given by:

$\vec u(t) = e^{t A} \vec u(0) + \displaystyle \int_0^t e^{(t-s) A} f(s) ~ ds = \dfrac{b}{2} \displaystyle \int_0^t \begin{bmatrix}1 + e^{-2a(t-s)}  \\ 1 - e^{-2a(t-s)}  \end{bmatrix}ds = \dfrac{b}{4 a} \begin{bmatrix}2 a  t + 1 -  e^{-2 a t}  \\ 2 a t - 1 + e^{-2 a t} \end{bmatrix} $

You should redo the problem using [*Undetermined Coefficients*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousSystems.aspx) (see example) and make sure you also know that method.

Comment: Amazing detailed explanation. Also, thank you for the links!